# Sum keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

The following code:

```
for j in reversed(range(0,15)):
  print i
  successors = g.successors(totuple(total_nodes[j,:]))
  array = [0,0,0,0]
  a=0
  i = i+1

  for succ in successors:
    print g.node[succ]
    array[a]=g.node[succ]
    a+=1      

    print array
    print sum(item['key'] for item in array)
```

produces the following output:

```
 1
 {'key': 0.0}
 {'key': 0.39730768970355257}
 {}
 {'key': 0.0}

 [{'key': 0.0}, {'key': 0.39730768970355257}, {}, {'key': 0.0}]
```

1. I don't get why some nodes don't have keys {}. But suppose I want to disregard those.
2. I want to sum those values or 'keys'

So based on other questions I tried:

1. `print sum(item['key'] for item in array)` produces:

   > KeyError: 'key'
2. `print sum([i for i in array.values()])` produces:

   > AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the last line to this in order to avoid key errors:

```
sum(item['key'] for item in array if 'key' in item)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sum(item.get('key', 0)) for item in array)` which would return `0` if `key` is not found

Answer (score 0):

Some of your nodes are lists or integers -- which is why, not being dicts, they don't have a `values()` method and can't be indexed with string keys.

As for why your data is structured so, we can't tell you unless you give us more context (like, what's `g`? What does `successors()` do? `totuple()`? What is the actual problem you're attempting to solve?).